# fastlane - cant publish to google playstore

Tags: flutter, cloud, fastlane, codemagic

I can't publish my **App Bundle** to Google PlayStore via Google Cloud and CodeMagic.io.

The Error is below:

> **Publishing failed :| Failed to publish: The bundle targets unrecognized languages: fb**

Previously, this **AppBundle** build using Flutter.

any idea how to solve this error?

**Update:**

If I choose to build **APK** instead of **App Bundle**. it will succeed to be uploaded to the play store.

Although the size increase from **23 MB** to **31 MB...**

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I added this to the app build.gradle under the defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
}
```